# preventing duplicate text

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using Composables in Android Studio Kotlin, It creates a spanned string via specified keywords via looking up within foreach loop, How to make it append just one time or remove duplicated appended text?

```
buildAnnotatedString {
    note.value.title.forEachIndexed { index, character ->
        append(character)

        if (index > queryString.count() - 1 && note.value.title.substring(
                index - (queryString.count() + 1 - 1), index
            ) == queryString
        ) {
            withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = Color.Blue))
            {
                append(queryString)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Actually its not possible to avoid writing two times or reverse code and delete duplicates